# Menu bar full, some items are not shown

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I have many programs in my menu bar like dropbox and watts, so many that the menu bar is now full.So some items are not shown in the menu bar.How do I force the menu bar to show all items?

This is the menu bar:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Fortunately I had enough space, I changed the clock format to analog:

[image]

Comment: What do you actually mean by the 'menu bar'? Do you mean the dock? The only way to get it to show all items is to reduce the size of the dock.

Comment: I mean the menu bar at the top of the screen, what's called a panel on ubuntu.

Comment: Is there even enough space to force it to show all menu bar items? Have you tried hiding your name to increase the space available for icons? There are plenty of guides on how to do so.

Comment: Yes, there is space.Between "Help" and the stack exchange notifier there should be the dropbox icon.

Comment: You say there is space, but from your image i wouldn't consider that space, even if there is technically enough of it to accommodate the Dropbox icon! Try hiding your name as i suggested?

Comment: I just changed the clock from digital to analog and now there is enough space.

Comment: btw I also removed some items, including the name.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a dumb solution, but can you make your resolution bigger?  It's probably a round about way to solve the problem.

Comment: This way I get a different resolution, I would stick to the one I'm using, which is optimal.Maybe changing just the menu bar icons resolution and keep the current resolution for the rest of the screen? Is that doable?

Comment: I have no idea on a mac.  On the flip side, on windows some of those icons can auto hide themselves in a sort of hiding menu.  Maybe apple does something similar that would allow you to only show the ones you really absolutely needed out 100% of the time.  Like, clock, temp, volume?  Changing the text size could work too if that's possible maybe, or the spacing between the menu items possibly.  I have no idea if that stuffs possible though.